# How is this possible - Older record with more recent created_at date?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

[image]

I see that I have two records, but the older one (smaller id) has a newer created_at date than the newer record (with older created_at)

My question is how was this possible.

Comment: how are you setting `created_at` ?

Comment: Rails is managing that.. Model.create ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two likely scenarios, since Rails lets the database handle the ID assignment:

1. If you're running a multi-server production environment, then clock drift could be a factor, or just simple race conditions between the two servers (see #2)
2. Two requests called two separate Ruby threads at the same time, and again a race condition occurred where the later-created object won the `INSERT`

[Read more here about the Race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)